# AnyLogic - Source Arrivals. Help setting up from sourced data

Tags: anylogic

I am creating a model where we have noted the time arrivals come each day.

Each time there was an arrival, we recorded the time in minutes starting at 0.00.

Example:

Arrival 1 - 4.09 minutes

Arrival 2 - 6.01 minutes

Arrival 3 - 9.04 minutes

etc

These are all listed in an Excel spreadsheet, and was repeated over 5 days (5 columns in total). So I have 5 columns of arrival times, with each row indicated the arrival number.

What's the best way to set this up?

I try Arrivals Defined by Database, but it then gets messy when I see arrival date, and then trying to set the columns. I then seem to keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dynamic Events in this case. Read the information as csv or text and assign it to a variable of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`, let's call it `arrivalData`. Create a dynamic event called `MyArrivalEvent`. In my case they take in the arguments `origin` and `destination`.

Then iterate through the arrayList and schedule the arrival events:

```
for (int i=0; i< 5; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j< arrivalData.size();i++) {
          create_MyArrivalEvent(arrivalData.get(j).get(i), MINUTE, origin, destination);
     }
}
```